# Why doesn't Stata and R produce the same output for a Multinomial Logit model?

Tags: r, stata, multinomial, mlogit

Let's say I want to do a simple multinomial logit model using an online dataset in R:

```
library(nnet)
data <- data.table(read.dta('http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/irished.dta'))
ml <- multinom(educg ~ gender + prestigeg + reasong, data=data)
summary(ml)
```

You get the following output

> summary(ml)
>       Call:
>       multinom(formula = educg ~ gender + prestigeg + reasong, data = data)

```
Coefficients:
          (Intercept) genderfemale prestigegQ2 prestigegQ3 prestigegQ4   reasongQ2 reasongQ3 reasongQ4
senior      -1.650999    0.3051297   0.8704957    1.189714    1.340206 -0.08303942  1.035163  1.627145
3rd level   -5.792979    0.1615402   1.5331076    1.682500    2.227006  2.11053104  3.232968  4.963707

Std. Errors:
          (Intercept) genderfemale prestigegQ2 prestigegQ3 prestigegQ4 reasongQ2 reasongQ3 reasongQ4
senior      0.3203241    0.2304163   0.3023462   0.3376034   0.3288158 0.2990188 0.3063954 0.3488479
3rd level   1.1165939    0.3477700   0.5534933   0.5878517   0.5433370 1.0789145 1.0644124 1.0532858

Residual Deviance: 730.8832 
AIC: 762.8832
```

If I perform a similar routine in Stata:

```
use http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/irished.dta
mlogit educg gender prestigeg reasong
```

I get the following output:

```
Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -433.16499  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -376.86517  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -371.52279  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -371.42355  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -371.42343  
Iteration 5:   log likelihood = -371.42343  

Multinomial logistic regression                 Number of obs     =        435
                                                LR chi2(6)        =     123.48
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -371.42343                     Pseudo R2         =     0.1425

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       educg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
junior       |  (base outcome)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
senior       |
      gender |   .2577712   .2247087     1.15   0.251    -.1826498    .6981921
   prestigeg |   .4394042   .1027884     4.27   0.000     .2379427    .6408657
     reasong |   .5584275   .1059711     5.27   0.000     .3507279     .766127
       _cons |  -2.890597    .533933    -5.41   0.000    -3.937086   -1.844108
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
3rd_level    |
      gender |   .1360704   .3416126     0.40   0.690    -.5334779    .8056188
   prestigeg |   .6387618   .1532933     4.17   0.000     .3383125    .9392111
     reasong |   1.431763    .197151     7.26   0.000     1.045355    1.818172
       _cons |  -7.032375   .9904472    -7.10   0.000    -8.973616   -5.091134
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why are these values completely different?  How do I get Stata-like output for a multinomial logit model in R?

Comment: Because it pretty clearly says, "junior       |  (base outcome)."  If anything, it's harder to tell the reference group from the R output.

Comment: From the Stata output it seems that Stata is treating `prestigeg` and `reasong` as numeric variables, whereas R treats them as factors.  Try `multinom(educg ~ gender + as.numeric(prestigeg) + as.numeric(reasong), data=data)` and compare the results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Stata to treat your covariates as factors rather than continuous variables:

```
. use https://grodri.github.io/datasets/irished, clear
(Irish Educational Transitions)

. mlogit educg i.(gender prestigeg reasong), nolog

Multinomial logistic regression                         Number of obs =    435
                                                        LR chi2(14)   = 135.45
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0000
Log likelihood = -365.44159                             Pseudo R2     = 0.1563

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       educg | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
junior       |  (base outcome)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
senior       |
      gender |
     female  |   .3051277   .2304158     1.32   0.185     -.146479    .7567344
             |
   prestigeg |
         Q2  |   .8704873   .3023455     2.88   0.004     .2779009    1.463074
         Q3  |   1.189704   .3376027     3.52   0.000     .5280148    1.851393
         Q4  |   1.340194   .3288149     4.08   0.000     .6957287    1.984659
             |
     reasong |
         Q2  |  -.0830386   .2990186    -0.28   0.781    -.6691042     .503027
         Q3  |   1.035168   .3063952     3.38   0.001     .4346448    1.635692
         Q4  |   1.627113   .3488457     4.66   0.000     .9433884    2.310838
             |
       _cons |   -1.65099   .3203233    -5.15   0.000    -2.278812   -1.023167
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
3rd_level    |
      gender |
     female  |   .1615339   .3477705     0.46   0.642    -.5200838    .8431517
             |
   prestigeg |
         Q2  |     1.5331   .5534948     2.77   0.006     .4482699     2.61793
         Q3  |   1.682486   .5878532     2.86   0.004     .5303152    2.834657
         Q4  |   2.226992   .5433381     4.10   0.000     1.162069    3.291915
             |
     reasong |
         Q2  |   2.110641   1.078963     1.96   0.050    -.0040878    4.225369
         Q3  |   3.233068   1.064462     3.04   0.002     1.146761    5.319375
         Q4  |   4.963772   1.053335     4.71   0.000     2.899273     7.02827
             |
       _cons |  -5.793072   1.116641    -5.19   0.000    -7.981649   -3.604496
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```